# How to convert a JsonNode containing a list of string to a comma separated string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

JsonNode:

```
{
  name: ["bishal", "jaiswal", "Turtle"],
  title: "jaiswal"
}
```

I want to extract the list of `name` from jsonNode as a comma separated string in an efficient way:

Output:

```
nameList ="bishal,jaiswal,Turtle"
```

Apart from converting the jsonNode of `name` array to a list & then using the join method to make the comma separated string. Any better way to do this ?

Comment: If you are using a framework to read the JSON into an object, that framework might provide a feature to do so, like the ResponseContainer in Swagger.
If you do not use a framework, you can use simple String operations on it, like split.

Comment: is there any way in which after accessing the `name` key from json, we can directly convert that jsonNode object to a comma separated string directly without applying too many operation, now i am converting the jsonNode to a List using ObjectMapper and then using the join method on the list to generate the comma separated string, is there any better way to do that?

Comment: You can use Jackson JSON in this case. 
For e.g. `JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
JsonNode title = rootNode.path("title");`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the hack

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree("{\"name\":[\"bishal\",\"jaiswal\",\"Turtle\"],\"title\":\"jaiswal\"}");
    final JsonNode name = jsonNode.get("name");
    final Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = name.iterator();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        final JsonNode next = iterator.next();
        if(s.length() > 0){
            s.append(",");
        }
        s.append(next);
    }
    System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: Already mentioned in the question, need to do this without converting it to a list and then changing it to a comma separated string.

Comment: Using iterator is similar approach as I have to traverse the whole jsonNode array.. this works, but I was looking for something else. Still thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, Jackson  Framework doesn't have any utility method to join sting in jsonNode. That's why we need to travel over an array or we can use string.join() which is more preferable than traversing over the array. Let's hope in the future Jackson will release support for such a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Jackson JSON in this case...
>
> Jackson is a very popular and efficient java based library to serialize or map Java objects to JSON and vice versa
>
> For e.g.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData); //jsonData is your json string here...
JsonNode names = rootNode.path("name");

Iterator<JsonNode> elements = names.elements();

while(elements.hasNext()){
    JsonNode name = elements.next();
    System.out.println("Names are = "+name);
}
```

Please can you let me know if this has solved your problem? Thanks